# How to Create an HKLM entry in Azure Website

Tags: azure, registry, azure-web-app-service

How do you create an entry in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) of an Azure Website?  The web application only needs to read the entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in Azure Web Sites.

if your application absolutely needs an access to Registry, you must target Azure Web Role (classic Cloud Service).

Answer (score 1):

The following page states the common baseline OS functionality for all apps running on Azure App Service and includes a section on "Registry access": https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality/

Apps have **read-only access to much of the registry** of the host VM. However, **no access whatsoever to the HKCU** hive is supported and **write-access to the registry is blocked** (as at 26/01/2016).