# How do I add a new TimeZone in registry during Web App deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are currently in process of migrating our on-premise web application to Azure Web App.

For one of the functionality, we had to add a new timezone in our web servers (namely, "Mountain Time Daylight Saving Time"). We added that in the registry under "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones". Application reads timezone from there and uses it further to convert the display time. This all works in our on-premise deployment model.

Now, while migrating this application to Azure Web App, we would also require this entry to get added in the registry of all web servers where the application is going to be hosted.

This way, we will not need to change the application logic, as the application will read the registry value, and use it.

Could anyone please help out with the approach of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19769068

Comment: Not sure you can achieve this while migrating your sites. But you can achieve this by adding WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE setting into your Application Settings.
You need to add an Application Setting (via the portal or the management APIs) called WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set that to the name of the time zone as defined in the Windows Registry under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ (for example, “Mountain Time Daylight Saving Time”).
Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/

Comment: by this I can add only one entry. And also how do we specify the value there? it seems that we are specifying key name, but not value by using this method. I.e., where is the provision where I can mention something like "(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan" in the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone please help out with the approach of how to achieve this?

[Writing to registry](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#writing-to-registry) is not allowed on the Azure WebApp. By default, your AppServices run in UTC.

As Askok mentioned that we could add the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE in the Azure [WebApp appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings).We could get the supported value from [Time Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)#time-zones).