# How to solve "Request Header Too Long" on an Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, iis, asp.net-core-2.0, query-string

Users logging in to our admin portal are assigned rights via Active Directory. Increasingly they are hitting a 400 error Bad Request (Request Header too long) error.

This is documented by Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request

Their proposed solution is to add two registry entries - MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes - which control the amount of data allowed in a URL.

However our websites are setup in Azure as Web Applications. According to various sources, including this SO question - [How to Create an HKLM entry in Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768929/how-to-create-an-hklm-entry-in-azure-website) - you can't change the registry on a Web Application.

Is there any way round this? The other solution suggested by MS is, amusingly, to "Decrease the number of Active Directory groups that the user is a member of". But we've already got that down to two yet the problem persists. The largest component of the URL is a 'state' parameter in the QueryString.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using asp.net-core-2.0 given as per your tag. You can configure this on the `WebHost` using `.UseKestrel(x => x ...)`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            // This is the line you want to add!
            .UseKestrel(x =>
            {
                x.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = <your value?>;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

There are more options available, like `MaxRequestHeaderCount` and `MaxRequestLineSize`.